# how to disable/change shortcut for entering unicode and ??? characters

Tags: kubuntu

Problem, tldr: crtl+shift+u and ctrl+. enters unicode char / something and I want to turn it off or be able to reassign it to better shortcut.

Background: I attempted to move from fedora to ubuntu, kde spin. Maybe it's related only to that distribution, I don't know. Sadly, KDE has something very non-standard with keyboard input, which makes it unusable for me, so I moved back to old and proven cinnamon. I just installed cinnamon package, kde is still installed. Maybe this is the cause, but I cannot cheaply reinstall whole machine now.

Everything is fine But, I'm still missing 2 shortcuts. One is for unicode input, 'ctrl+shift+u', which I can theoretically live with (but I don't want to), and second is 'ctrl+.', I don't even know what that is.

I might be wrong, but IIRC in last 20 years I needed to quickly enter unicode character ~zero times. Both of these shortcuts are too prestigious to be allocated for something what is close to never used (unicode input), respectively never used and I even don't know what that is. Especially ctrl+. is very nice shortcut, used in many IDEs, and I don't want to loose it just because there is something I will never use.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

So it turned out, that ctrl-. is for emoji input. Yes, indeed, that has to be turned on by default.

to change shortcuts to something else run `ibus-setup` or uninstall ibus to get rid of this altogether.